# k8smaster server works like a worker

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I deploy my Spring projects to Kubernetes with Jenkins. I have k8smaster and 3 worker servers. It sometimes writes .m2 files under the k8smaster server. How can I prevent this? So I want it to write only on worker servers.

**kubernetes nodes**

[image]

I defined a label with a special name in Jenkins so that the job does not run on the master server, but it still works like a worker.
[image]
[image]

**Jenkins List of volumes to mount in agent pod**
[image]

**Pod Template Settings**
[image]

**Example pipeline**

```
node ("zrgl-label") {
    stage('Checkout'){
        cleanWs()
        withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: 'zrgl.jenkins')]){
            sh 'git clone -b ..'
        }
    }
    stage('Kubernetes Deployment'){
            container('kubectl'){
                 ...
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you don't like that Jenkins will run jobs on K8S master.
If so, I suggest just don't run Jenkins on K8S master.

Comment: Actually, I don't want k8smaster to run the pods, after all, the master server has the "control-plane" role. I want it to work only in workers. I shared the details in the topic I opened for this. I want the pods to run only in the workers and write the .m2 files only to the workers where the pods are deployed, not to the master.

Comment: I see. Good point! AFAIK, K8S doesn't run pods on the master. 
I suggest to check if 'NoSchedule' taint is configured on your master - https://gauravguptacloud.medium.com/no-pod-on-master-node-why-kubernetes-6afb07b05ce6.

Comment: Why doesn't the label definition in Jenkins provide this? Also, how do you think I should introduce my master's degree? Do I need to do anything in my Deployment.yaml files after defining Taint?

Comment: "Why doesn't the label definition in Jenkins provide this? " - I'm not sure.

But as I said I suggest to read link I shared, or just google "how to prevent pods from running on k8s master". Jenkins is just one application, obviously you'll have more deployments in your k8s.